# Link Detection / String to Link (even without www)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, hyperlink, autolink

**Case:** A User's Profile where he can add a bunch of links.

I collect the links via the User Registration Page, but i'm having a Problem with Users not entering www. and http:// in front of the URL.

I could fix the http:// problem with [auto_link](https://github.com/tenderlove/rails_autolink) but i have to many users just typing `example.com`.

> How can i extract the URL from a String, even if it is without www. or http:// (The field contains
>   ONLY the url).

Display Code:

```
<% if @user.website.present? %>
  <li>
    <%= link_to @user.website, target: '_blank' do %>
      <i class="fa fa-globe"></i> <span>Website</span>
    <% end %>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

Comment: something like "example.com/foo/bar".gsub(/\A(http:\/\/)?(www\.)?(.*)/,"http://www.\\3") ?

Comment: Giasou Stavro. Yeah i thought about Regexp, but i don't know how to implement it in my Model correctly. Could you Describe it a little more ?

Comment: Check the answer, which, if you wish, I can improve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following sample urls:

```
text1="example.com/foo/bar"
text2="www.example.com/foo/bar"
text3="http://www.example.com/foo/bar"
text4="https://www.example.com/foo/bar"
```

This:

```
gsub(/\A(http(s)?:\/\/)?(www\.)?(.*)/,"http\\2://www.\\4")
```

will output the following:

```
text1.gsub(/\A(http(s)?:\/\/)?(www\.)?(.*)/,"http\\2://www.\\4") 
# http://www.example.com/foo/bar

text2.gsub(/\A(http(s)?:\/\/)?(www\.)?(.*)/,"http\\2://www.\\4") 
# http://www.example.com/foo/bar

text3.gsub(/\A(http(s)?:\/\/)?(www\.)?(.*)/,"http\\2://www.\\4") 
# http://www.example.com/foo/bar

text4.gsub(/\A(http(s)?:\/\/)?(www\.)?(.*)/,"http\\2://www.\\4") 
# https remains
# https://www.example.com/foo/bar
```

So, if you want to use link_to external link:

```
<%= link_to '<i class="fa fa-globe"></i> <span>Website</span>'.html_safe, 
    @user.website.
    gsub(/\A(http(s)?:\/\/)?(www\.)?(.*)/,"http\\2://www.\\4") unless
    @user.website.nil? %>
```

**Edit:**

The above case will have a bad exception.

```
text5="http://example.com/foo/bar"
```

the above substitution will return

```
http://www.example.com/foo/bar # inserting a "www"
```

which is not ok for most cases. So, you must provide a condition to substitute. I'd suggest you create a helper method like this:

```
def url_to_external(text)
    /\Ahttp(s)?:\/\//.match(text) ? text : text.gsub(/\A(http(s)?:\/\/)?(www\.)?(.*)/,"http\\2://www.\\4")
end
```

Which will only replace if there is no "http://" or "https://" at the start of the string.

In your view, then:

```
<%= link_to '<i class="fa fa-globe"></i> <span>Website</span>'.html_safe,
    url_to_external(@user.website) unless @user.website.nil? %>
```